# Dynamically added table rows not appearing

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have seen many posts regarding dynamically adding table rows, but I am not sure what I'm missing.

When I execute the following, nothing is displayed (aside from application title bar).

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_view_test_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tvt_scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            >
        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvt_scroll_relative"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tvt_tableview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.table_view);

    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tvt_tableview);

    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView column1 = new TextView(this);
    column1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    column1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    column1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    column1.setText("Col1 Value");
    tableRow.addView(column1);

    TextView column2 = new TextView(this);
    column2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    column2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    column2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    column2.setText("Col2 Value");
    tableRow.addView(column2);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //tl.refreshDrawableState();
    //findViewById(R.id.tvt_scroll_relative).refreshDrawableState();
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  This all looks good to me (not that I am absolutely sure of anything here...).  I will recommend trying to dynamically add other `TextView`'s to the other layouts above the `TableLayout`.  See if you can get *something* to show up.  Let us know how it works out.

Comment: remove the line tableRow.setLayoutParams(); after you have instantiated TableRow, it should work i think. Let me know if this works, so that i can post it as a solution.

Comment: @Yashwanth Kumar, removing that alone did not help. Changing ViewGroup.LayoutParams to TableRow.LayoutParams or removing them altogether does resolve the issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the two references

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams
```

to

`TableRow.LayoutParams`

and it should work.

Adding layout params to a widget requires that the `LayoutParams` are a inner class of the surrounding layout container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have a reference for using the inner class of the surrounding layout container?

Comment: I had the same problem and discovered it after a some experiencing.   I would be interested in some reference, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has something to do with you setting the layout params to the `TextView`s. If you remove those definitions the info appears. Also if you take a look at the official documentation for `TableRow` you can see:

`The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.`

Comment: Not entirely true, as you can set `TableRow.LayoutParams.span`, in which case you will need to set the `LayoutParam`s.